# android : loading images : one url

Tags: java, android

I want to load all images from one link

```
public final class Constants {

    public static final String[] IMAGES = new String[] {
    // Heavy
    "http://domin.com/files/asmabanat/*.jpg", //load all images in this link : *.jpg (1.jpg - 2.jpg ..atc) OR load all images in one web page .

    };

    private Constants() {
    }
}
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: i can put a link for each image
But this is not what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

Unless you do your own method that generate URLs and try them one by one (which I think is not affordable at all), I think this is not possible to do what you want (as you neither can do that in other environments).

**---- EDIT ----**

Here would be an example of the mechanism to test whether an URL exists or not.

```
int counter = 0;
boolean keep_loading = true;

while (keep_loading) {
  final URL url = new URL("http://domin.com/files/asmabanat/" + counter + ".jpg");
  HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  int responseCode = huc.getResponseCode();

  if (resposeCode != 404) {
    // This would mean that the image exists
    // Here you have to do the Lazy Loading of that image
    // You may find a good example of Lazy Loading of images
    // at this URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview

    ...
    counter++;
  }
  else {
    // This means the URL returned a 404 error, which means your last image
    // was the last that exists, so you just get out of the loop
    keep_loading = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Even if i owned the site , and I'll put images digital sequence (1.jpg - 2.jpg - 3.jpg ...atc )?

Comment: If you know how your images are stored, that changes the thing. You would need to construct the URL generator (in your case, a number generator which can be easily implemented by a `for` loop, specifying `i.jpg`) and download them. As it seems to be, I strongly recommend using Lazy loading (an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

Comment: But that will not allow me to add images in the future

Comment: You can make run your method until the first http request returns a 404 error (not found). That means that the last of your images was the last of your server. So next time, if you add 5 more images, they will be processed until the first 404 error, this way you assure yourself you're processing all images within your server.

Comment: can you give me an example of a simple code . thank you